# Cordova 2.3.0 DeviceReady not firing on Blacberry OS 5 and higher

Tags: javascript, cordova

I called a DeviceReady event via Android and it works. Added an alert in Cordova-2.3.0.js and it works in Android. It just dont seem to work in blackberry.
Any reason why this happens ? Im using a blackberry 9900.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same Cordova-2.3.0.js file from Android?  I had the same troubles with Android/iOS because the file differs between OSs.  I ended up creating a new project with iOS, copying the js file over to my old project, and having two distinct Cordova files in my js folder.

I used this number to switch between them:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var is_ios = ((/iphone|ipad/gi).test(navigator.appVersion));
    var is_android = ((/android/gi).test(navigator.appVersion));
    var is_blackberry = ((/blackberry/gi).test(navigator.appVersion));
    var scripts = new Array();
    if (is_ios) {
        scripts.push('cordova-2.2.0.ios.js');
        scripts.push('ios_plugins.js');
    } else if (is_android) {
        scripts.push('cordova-2.2.0.android.js');
        scripts.push('android_plugins.js');
    } else if (is_blackberry) {
        scripts.push('cordova-2.2.0.blackberry.js');
        scripts.push('blackberry_plugins.js');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++)
        document.write('<script charset="utf-8" src="js/' + scripts[i] + '"><\/script>');           
</script>
```

Granted, I'm not sure if the blackberry addition will work ... you can give it a go and adjust as needed.